# Google Analytics Tracking Events

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

In our Google Analytics, we have a couple of events showing up that we have not set them up! By that, I mean, I haven't trigger those events from our website, neither through codes (`ga.send('event')`), nor through Google Tag Manager. I just can't figure out where they're populating from. To be specific, they're "Video" and "Livechat" events.

Is it possible that Analytics have ways of figuring some obvious events and track them for us?

Comment: i'm just seeing this now. Thanks for the response. Great tip about pulling in hostname, can use for future reference, but it wasn't an issue in this case.
You're exactly right about the third parties having to do with it. Some video platforms such as Wistia automatically send tracking information in, but not all platforms, for example with YouTube you'll have to enable your own custom tracking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics does not send events on it's own. More likely scenarios are:

- You are using third party integrations for video and livechat and
  they include Google Analytics code that sends to your property (and
  possibly others)
- Someone else is using your tracking id in their site (you can check this by setting hostname as secondary dimension in your event reports)